# Fix thread counts based on records count

Tags: jmeter

I have a requirement to run a query on Oracle DB and fetch account numbers, the number of thread counts will be fixed based on number of records returned from DB.

I am able to fetch account numbers by using JDBC and write in a csv. But i couldn't crack the logic of fixing the thread count based on number of records.

Need your inputs on this scenario to fix the thread count.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

1. [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) to fetch the records from the database and storing it into the file
2. [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) or [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function in the "normal" Thread Group to read the number of accounts from the CSV file. The Thread Group will kick off as many threads as it will be in the file.